# Can someone explain the recurrence relations for quad and binary partitions for searching in a sorted table?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

If you have a square region that holds various numbers, what is the result of each recurrence relation?:

T(n) = 3T(n/2) + c and T(n) = 2T(n/2) + cn

I know the first is supposed to result in a quad partition and the second a binary partition, but I can't intuitively wrap my head around *why* this is the case.  Why are we making 3 recursive calls in the first case and 2 in the second?  Why does the +c or +cn effect what we're doing with the problem?

Comment: A bit more info on your question? what exactly is the square region? and how are you recursing? Because the first one simply gives you three recursive calls, if you draw recursion tree cost at each call will be a constant c.

Comment: The table is sorted along its rows and columns, and the algorithm is trying to search for some particular value in the region.  The first recurrence is a "quad partition" approach, while the second is a "binary partition" approach.

Comment: Any connection between your textual mention of "quad" and "binary" partitions and your recurrence formulas is completely unclear;  if you want someone to understand and explain that connection, you have not provided anywhere near enough context.  Do you have a reference?

Comment: The first is reportedly splitting the region into four quadrants, where one can be eliminated.  The second is reportedly splitting the region into four quadrants, while eliminating 2 of the 4 sub-regions.  I'm just curious as to how they accomplish these results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

http://leetcode.com/2010/10/searching-2d-sorted-matrix-part-ii.html

if your question is just about the recursion explanation, I recommend reading up on solving recurrences using recursion tree and the master method

http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/rec/rec08.pdf

This explains the second recurrence and the method. Basically you will have a recursion tree with height (lgn) and the cost at each level equalling n.

In the first one the recursion tree will have run time of the order of number of nodes in the tree. The height will still be lgn but the cost at each level 3^h * c. Summation over this will give you the complexity